# $('#my_form').ajaxForm opening PHP page instead of reloading content (Safari,Chrome)

Tags: jquery, response, ajaxform

My ajaxForm request is not working properly in Safari and Chrome. **Instead of getting the response from php file it opens it as a new page.** (Works fine in FF, IE, Opera):

```
$('#my_form').ajaxForm({
    success: finished
}); 
    function finished(responseText, statusText)  {
...
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: before or after the function call success?

Answer (score 3):

in the same plugin can find this example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').bind('submit', function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            target: '#output'
        });
        return false; // <-- important!
    });
});
```

You can do this in the same form in the onSubmit event:

```
<form ... onSubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: Adding 'onsubmit="return false;"' to the form tag worked for me.